# Marlin Firmware Auto Leveling only re-centers the XY-axis (Delta printer)

Tags: marlin, delta, bed-leveling

I'm trying to get my printer to auto level its bed, with Marlin firmware using the following:

- Printer: Kossel Linear plus (Delta 3D printer)
- Board: MKS Base V1.5
- Firmware: Marlin customized

I go into the menu on my LCD, and go to the prepare screen. The screen has the following options:

- Auto home
- Level Bed
- Bed leveling: off

When I select the "Auto home" function, the printer uses the stops at the top of the delta to zero itself.
When I select the "Level bed" function, the printer once again uses the end stops to level itself.
If I turn the Bed leveling to ON, then the Level Bed function will do the exact same thing.

My auto-leveling device is connected to the Z-axis end-stop, and looks like so:

[image: Auto-leveling device connected to the Z-axis end-stop]

I have the `#define AUTO_BED_LEVELING_LINEAR` line in my config.h, as well as the `#define Z_MIN_PROBE_USES_Z_MIN_ENDSTOP_PIN` line. I'm not sure why the printer doesn't actually lower the head to the plate and press the endstop.

Any clues as to how to make the printer level the bed and not home the XY axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to define the constants `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_LINEAR` and `Z_MIN_PROBE_USES_Z_MIN_ENDSTOP_PIN`, be sure to define the following also:

```
#define Z_MAX_POS MANUAL_Z_HOME_POS
```

and

```
#define MANUAL_Z_HOME_POS 300 // Distance between the nozzle to printbed after homing
```

- *Note that 300 should be the distance from nozzle to bed after homing.*

Please look into the configuration files of this [Kossel Linear Plus](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2784940/files) and compare them with your own configuration files, you may have missed something.